# Using installer to pin application to start menu

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project

I am making an installer for my application using visual studio installer.I was wondering if there is any way to "pin" my application to the "Windows Start Menu" using the installer

Answer (score 0):

You really should **[not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378460%28VS.85%29.aspx)** be doing this - pinning and unpinning is [meant to be a user action / preference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/03/54760.aspx). No matter how amazing your application might be, it is up to the user if they want to pin it or not.

> A small set of applications are pinned by default for new
> installations. Other than these, **only the user can pin further
> applications; programmatic pinning by an application is not permitted.**

There are ways around this limitation, i.e: [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2009/04/08/pin-items-to-the-start-menu-or-windows-7-taskbar-via-script.aspx) and [this](http://blog.ananthonline.net/?p=37). But even there it notes that you are not supposed to be doing this.

Comment: I am quite new to vs installer.Do you mean I use such a code in a custom action?

Comment: @Alaa [this](http://blog.ananthonline.net/?p=37) link provides a C# class which you could use to do this from a custom action (I stress though that you're not actually meant to be doing this, Microsoft didn't provide an API for a reason).